# Weird constructor call

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class which does all its work in the constructor (it is constructed there, runs some calculacions, outputs them, and then it is destructed all this in constructor).

here is simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>

class myInt {
public:
    myInt(int init) : mInt(init) {}

    int mInt;
};

class SinglePara {
public:
    SinglePara(myInt first) : member(first.mInt) { std::cout << member << std::endl; this->~SinglePara(); }

    int member;
};

class TwoPara {
public:
    TwoPara(myInt first, myInt second) : member1(first.mInt), member2(second.mInt) { std::cout << member1 + member2 << std::endl; this->~TwoPara(); }

    int member1, member2;
};

int main()
{
    myInt one(1), two(2), three(3);
    TwoPara myTwo(one, two);      // outputs 3 as expected
    TwoPara(one, two);            // outputs 3 as expected

    SinglePara mySingle(three);   // outputs 3 as expected
    SinglePara(three);            // won´t compile

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Now the first 3 examples in my code behave exactly in the way I would expect them to. But the last one won´t even compile because it thinks I want to call copy constructor even though `three` is `myInt`. When `SinglePara` and `TwoPara` take as arguments integers instead of `myInt` then all four examples behave as I want them to.

Can someone explain this behaviour and tell me how to fix the fourth example if possible?

I´m using MSVC 2013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your

```
SinglePara(three);
```

is equivalent to

```
SinglePara three;
```

It is just a declaration for object `three` with a pair of redundant `()` around the name. But you already have an object named `three` declared before. You cannot declare another one in the same scope. Hence the error.

You apparently wanted your `SinglePara(three)` to be an expression that creates a temporary object of type `SinglePara`. Typically it happens "by itself" when you use in a context that unambiguously indicates that it is an expression. In your case you used it without context, creating the "expression vs. declaration" ambiguity, which always gets resolved in favor of declaration.

If you really just want to create a short-lived temporary, something expression-specific will help to push the compiler in proper direction. For example, a fictive use of comma operator will make it unambiguously an expression

```
SinglePara((0, three)); // OK
0, SinglePara(three); // OK
```

As a solution this is rather inelegant, but it does illustrate the nature of the problem. For a better solution, as it has been suggested in the comments, you can add a pair of parentheses

```
(SinglePara(three));
```

the make the compiler to recognize it as an expression.

Comment: Actually, you can simply surround the expression in parentheses: `(SinglePara(three))`.

Comment: Is this a case of the most vexing parse? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: @ta.speot.is: No. The most vexing parse is a very specific ambiguity between object declaration and function declaration. In this case we have an ambiguity between object declaration and expression. It is a different ambiguity, not formally referred as "the most vexing parse". Although these days everything seems to be indiscriminately called "the most vexing parse"

Comment: Since OP is using MSVC 2013, a better solution is to use C++11 uniform initialization, i.e. `SinglePara{three};`.